# How to use chutzpah's ExpandReferenceComments for References

Tags: chutzpah

I'm using the chutzpah JavaScript test runner in Visual Studio 2015

I'm trying to take all reference tags out of my scripts files (eg. `/// <reference path="_references.js"/>`).

I've added:

```
"References": [
    {
      "Path": "chutzpah/_references.js",
      "ExpandReferenceComments": "true"
    }
  ]
```

to my chutzpah.json config.

but the reference tags in _references.js are still not being added to the tests.

a sample reference tag in _references.js is:

```
/// <reference path="../../MyApplication/js/lib/jquery-1.12.3.js"/>
```

They have a relative path to a separate project.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding where the relative path starts? But I have also tried `../MyApplication/js/lib/jquery-1.12.3.js` with the thought that it might become relative to chutzpah.json.

If I just include the references tag: `/// <reference path="_references.js"/>` everything works fine.

Comment: If you turn on tracing for Chutzpah it will tell you where it is looking. Can you try that and see?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It's the first thing I'd try next. Unfortunately, shortly after I posted the question I was put on a totally different project at work, so I'm not sure when I'll be able to get back to this.

Answer (score 0):

"ExpandReferenceComments" isn't a valid value for a Reference element. It's only valid for a Test element:

```
"Tests": [ { "Path": "Tests/*.js", "ExpandReferenceComments": true } ]
```

It doesn't expand the references in your References collection; it expands the references in the /// tags in your test scripts.

As for the path, it is relative to your solution. "../../" is solution root, "../" is project root.

FWIW, I've struggled with getting references to work properly; there seems to be too much order-sensitivity, so I've wound up having to use a hybrid combination of /// tags and chutzpah.json.References.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't yet gotten back to this problem, but "ExpandReferenceComments" is listed as a valid value for a Reference element in the [docu](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/references-setting).